# struggling summing my array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to fix a subroutine that creates an array of 10 Integers such that each element of the array stores the sum of its own index number and all previous indexes. (Indexes start at 1.) The values in the array would be:
1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55

For example, the value 6 in the 3rd element is the sum of the index values 1 + 2 + 3. At the end all I am doing is copying the contents of the array to the range A1:J1.

The code I have thus far goes as follows:

```
Sub SumNum()
    Dim Ints(1 to 10) As Integer
    Dim Sum As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    For i = LBound(Ints) to UBound(Ints)
        Sum = i + Ints(i)
    Range("A1").offset(0,1).Value = Sum
    Next i
End Sub
```

It seems in theory I guess that it should work out since I have the loop going and having the sum pasted to each offset, however this sub is giving me errors and unable to perform. Any guidance will be appreciated!

Edit: when I run my code the only output is on B2 of the value 10. Strange!

Comment: Where do you store any  value to Ints() ?

Comment: @RichHolton , On the second line, Ints(1 to 10) As Integer. It is a size of 10, thus it can have 10 values right?

Comment: It will be initialized to all zeros. Ints(1) will be 0, Ints(2) will be 0, etc.

Comment: An array is like a storage cabinet. You have 10 drawers,  but nothing in them.

Comment: Should I add these lines of code underneath,     Ints(1) = 1
    Ints(2) = 2
    Ints(3) = 3
    Ints(4) = 4
    Ints(5) = 5
    Ints(6) = 6
    Ints(7) = 7
    Ints(8) = 8
    Ints(9) = 9
    Ints(10) = 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Range("A1:J1").Formula = "=(COLUMN()*(COLUMN()+1))/2"
```

Two things to note here:

- You can assign a range to an array directly without looping. That is, after computing your array, you can say `myRange.Value = myArray`. You need to transpose the array if the range is a column.
- The above code exploits a known mathematical formula: `1+2+3+...+n = (n(n+1))/2`. It didn't need to compute any array. The formula applies this equation and gets the index from the `Column` property of each cell.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Replacing my range line with yours, did the trick, I was just wondering if you can tell me why you did "=(Column()*(column()+1))/2"

Comment: @JerrySilvera with pleasure, please read the added explanation :)

Comment: @JerrySilvera - Note: Don't just replace your range line with the one in the answer - replace the entire contents of your subroutine with it - e.g. `Sub SumNum()` `Range("A1:J1").Formula = "=(COLUMN()*(COLUMN()+1))/2"` `End Sub`.  (Or just type the formula itself [not the code] directly into Excel without the need for a subroutine.)